# How can add a foot separation line on a chapter page in KOMA Script?

Tags: koma-script

I am using a KOMA-Script. I want to add a foot separation line on a chapter page. I have tried using `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}`, but it also gives headings and head separation line, which I do not want.

```
% KOMA-Script code for header and footer font
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont} %font for header
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont} %font for footer
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\rmfamily} %font for page numbers

% Define width of header
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}

% Define with of header line
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}

% Define width of footer
\setfootwidth[0pt]{text}

% Define with of footer line 
\setfootsepline[text]{0.4pt}

% Define content of header and footer

% Using some scrpage2 commands here. The scrpage2 package is loaded here: 01_Preamble/KOMA-Script-Packages.tex

% Clear all defaults
\ohead{\text{\headmark}}

% Left (even page numbers) 
\lefoot%

[% scrplain style (begin)
\pagemark

]% scrplain style (end)

{
\pagemark
}% scrheadings style (end)

% Right (odd page numbers) 
\rofoot%

[% scrplain style (begin)
\pagemark

]% scrplain style (end)

{% scrplain style (begin)

\pagemark

}% scrplain style (end)

%
% #######################
% End: Header and Footer Customization
% #######################
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you pleae edit your question and add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

By default class option `footsepline` adds the rule above the footer on `plain` pages too:

```latex
\documentclass[footsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But it seems that you load package `scrlayer-scrpage`. Then you have to add the package option `plainheadsepline`:

```latex
\documentclass[footsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Additional remark: `scrlayer-scrpage` provides also option `footsepline` with a different syntax - you can adjust the thickness and the length of the rule using the package option (see the documentation). If you set `footsepline` or `footsepline=true` in the class or package options, `scrheadings` uses the default settings for the rule.

---

**Update** (added code snippet in the question)

Using the code snippet in your question I would suggest to switch to package `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[
  automark,
  headsepline,
  footsepline,plainfootsepline,
  headwidth=textwithmarginpar
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added "plainfootsepline" in scr package. It worked.
\usepackage[%
   automark,
 ilines,
 headsepline,
 footsepline,
 plainfootsepline
]{scrpage2}

Comment: Package `scrpage2` is outdated for about 6 years! I would suggest to switch to its successor `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have changed it to scrlayer-scrpage. :)

Comment: See my updated answer, I have added an additional example.

Comment: I have already upvoted the answer.